# Join específico entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tenho duas tabelas

clientes

| id | razao_social |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | empresa_1 |
| 2 | empresa_2 |

e tarefas

| id | id_cliente | tarefas | competencia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '101' | '032021' |
| 2 | 1 | '102' | '032021' |
| 3 | 2 | '101' | '032021' |

Quando eu faço um `join` entre essas tabelas, obtenho um resultado correto, mas NÃO é o que eu estou procurando:

```
select c.razao_social , s.tarefas , s.competencia 
from clientes c
join tarefas s on c.id = s.id_cliente
 where s.competencia = '032021'
 order by s.id_cliente;
```

Resultado obtido:

| razao_social | tarefas | competencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| empresa_1 | '101' | '032021' |
| empresa_1 | '102' | '032021' |
| empresa_2 | '101' | '032021' |

Resultado que eu gostaria de obter:

| razao_social | tarefas | competencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| empresa_1 | '101' | '032021' |
| empresa_1 | '102' | '032021' |
| empresa_2 | '101' | '032021' |
| empresa_2 | null ou vazio | '032021' |

(ou qualquer outra coisa que indique que a tarefa '102' não foi feita pra empresa_2)

Existe alguma consulta que me ajude a gerar essa tabela resultado? Eu posso (e estou) a usar a linguagem de programação pra corrigir essa "linha faltante", mas queria saber se tem outro jeito, a nível de consulta `SQL`.

Testado: aplicar `left join` ou `right join` foram insuficientes pra fazer o que eu quero.

Comment: é difícil fazer com um simples query isso, pq teu modelo não obriga que uma tarefa seja feita por mais de um cliente

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/3774)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [consultas aninhadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/composing-nested-entity-sql-queries), seguindo os dois passos seguintes:
**Primeiro:** Deve-se fazer uma consulta que resulte em um conjunto preliminar que chamarei de  *base* das informações desejadas;
**Segundo:** `Left Join` com as tabelas que foram utilizadas para construir a base.

**Primeiro passo - Obter *tabela base*:**

```
select distinct id_cliente, t2.tarefa, t.competencia  from tarefas t, 
    (select distinct tarefas as tarefa, competencia  from tarefas) t2
      where t.competencia = t2.competencia 
        and t.competencia = '032021'  
      order by id_cliente, t2.tarefa
```

**Resultado - *Tabela base*:**

| id_cliente | tarefa | competencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 032021 |
| 1 | 102 | 032021 |
| 2 | 101 | 032021 |
| 2 | 102 | 032021 |

Desta forma obtemos todos os clientes combinado com todas as tarefas e o campo `competencia`.

**Segundo passo: Usar a *tabela base* com `Left Join`:**
Tendo obtido a *tabela base* das combinações, agora basta fazer o `Left Join`, vejamos:

```
select c.razao_social, t3.tarefas, base.competencia from ( 
    select distinct id_cliente, t2.tarefa, t.competencia  from tarefas t, 
        (select distinct tarefas as tarefa, competencia  from tarefas) t2
     where t.competencia = t2.competencia 
       and t.competencia = '032021'  
     order by id_cliente, t2.tarefa 
) base left join clientes c on base.id_cliente = c.id 
       left join tarefas t3 on base.id_cliente = t3.id_cliente 
                           and base.tarefa = t3.tarefas 
                           and base.competencia = t3.competencia
```

**Resultado obtido:**

| razao_social | tarefas | competencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| empresa_1 | 101 | 032021 |
| empresa_1 | 102 | 032021 |
| empresa_2 | 101 | 032021 |
| empresa_2 | [NULL] | 032021 |

Desta forma é possível obter o resultado desejado.

Comment: Vi agora pouco sua postagem no meta sobre negativos. Não tenho muito como elaborar agora (e nem seria aqui na resposta), mas uma sugestão seria evitar postagens cuja resposta seja específica para o autor, este não é o objetivo do site. Tanto perguntas quanto respostas que fujam do [repositório coletivo de conhecimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70), tendem a ter uma recepção menos favorável do que perguntas e respostas canônicas (a pergunta aqui até está melhor que a média, mas provavelmente é duplicata, importante verificar. Meu comentário não é restrito a esta pergunta aqui).